# How to check/uncheck a checkbox in a modal form by using button (Bootstrap)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to check a checkbox in modal form with a click on assigned buttons in portfolio gallery (I do not want modal form to pop up each time its checked, the checking operation to be done in background, but show when a specific button for popping up modal form is clicked. buttons like order now.)
My HTML code for modal and gallery are as following:

**Modal Part**

```
    <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title w-100 text-center" >Fill your Enquiry</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body justify-content-center">
      <form action="mail_handler.php" method="POST" name="form" class="form-box">
        <div class="modal-body mx-3">
        <div class="form-group">
      <div class="form-row">
        <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="check1" name="tours[]" value="check1">
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="check1">Check1</label>
        </div>
        &nbsp; &nbsp;
        <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="Check2" name="tours[]" value="check2">
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="Check2">Check2</label>
        </div>
        &nbsp; &nbsp;
        <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="Check3" name="tours[]" value="check3">
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="Check3">Check3</label>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-row">
        <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="Check4" name="tours[]" value="Check4">
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="Check4">Check4</label>
        </div>
```

**Portfolio gallery part:**

```
<div class="section-title" data-aos="zoom-out-right">
  <h2>Gallery</h2>
  <p>galler details</p>
</div>
<div class="row portfolio-container" data-aos="zoom-out-right" data-aos-delay="400">

  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 portfolio-item">
    <div class="portfolio-wrap">
      <img src="">
      <div class="portfolio-info">
        <h4>Pcture 1</h4>
        <p>Picture 1 details </p>
        <div class="portfolio-links">
          <button id="checkmodal" type="button" class="buttonaa" class="check"><a><i class="bx bx-plus"></i></a></button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 portfolio-item">
    <div class="portfolio-wrap">
      <img src="">
      <div class="portfolio-info">
        <h4>Picture 2</h4>
        <p>Picture 2 details</p>
        <div class="portfolio-links">
         <button id="checkmodal" type="button" class="buttonaa" class="check"><a><i class="bx bx-plus"></i></a></button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 portfolio-item">
    <div class="portfolio-wrap">
      <img src="">
      <div class="portfolio-info">
        <h4>Picture 3</h4>
        <p>Picture 3 details</p>
        <div class="portfolio-links">
          <button id="checkmodal" type="button" class="buttonaa" class="check"><a><i class="bx bx-plus"></i></a></button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 portfolio-item">
    <div class="portfolio-wrap">
      <img src="">
      <div class="portfolio-info">
        <h4>Picture 4</h4>
        <p>Picture 4 details.</p>
        <div class="portfolio-links">
          <button id="checkmodal" type="button" class="buttonaa" class="check"><a><i class="bx bx-plus"></i></a></button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Note that I didn't add ending of both sections and just need a javascript to execute those however after googling for some days i didn't find it.
PS I'm not a web developer just learning now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im going to assume you mean you want a button on your page to "in the background" check a checkbox inside a modal without activating the modal

```js
function checkIt(x) {
  var checkbox = document.getElementById(x)
  if(!checkbox.checked) {
 checkbox.checked = true
  } else {
   checkbox.checked = false
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="myCheck">

<button onclick="checkIt('myCheck')">Change State</button>
```

To adapt this to your application, just replace the element ID with your own, and call the function on every button, and pass the ID of the checkbox you want affected from that button as an argument.